# how to add specific rows using Unix script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Hi I am Little Novice in Shell Scripting but facing issue in getting one of  the  simple result , which could be cake walk for most of people here.

I am looking for a shell script  where  I  can add specific rows only for a particular specific Column  .
Like out of the 6000 rows I like get the sum all the data in field 150 for only  rows starting from 33 to 58 only

I know it can be achieved through awk statement but i am making mistake when I am looping using NR

```
awk -F"|" '(NR=33;NR<36;NR++) {x += $150} end {printf ("%10d\n",x)}' <File name>.
```

Comment: Do you want to do stuff between lines 33 and 36? Is that why you are using NR in the condition part?

Answer (score 2):

You should let `awk` take care of the looping, only check the boundaries:

```
awk -F"|" '(NR > 32 && NR < 36) {sum +=$1} END {print sum}' filename
```